# Get value from edit field on a custom dialog and save in registry using InstallScript MSI Project type

Tags: installshield, customdialog, installscript-msi

I'm using Flexera InstallShield 2021.

**Background:** Before I was using the Basic MSI project where on the custom dialog I added an edit field and by using its "property" field I bound the property name with it. Further I use the [property name] while writing in the registry.

**Current Requirement:** I am switching to the InstallScript MSI project. I have created the custom dialog and also added the edit field to it. But there is no way to bind the text field to the property which further I could use to write in the registry. *How can I get the text entered by the user on the custom dialog so that i could write in the registry?*

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The process is still the same. The way you perform your current process is what has to change. I don't have InstallShield available in front of me but the Installscript MSI projects still binds properties to the dialog objects. Use the [MsiGetProperty](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/FAQPropertiesInstallScript.htm) function in your installscript to get the property associated with the object.

I believe searching that same site will yield results on how to write a property value to the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed the change by using scripting. @Doc mentioned the process is the same but it is not. The basic MSI project has a "property" field which holds the property name declared in "Property Manager". But in scripting, we don't have such property. To handle it I have used scripting and get/set values using `MsiGetProperty` & `MsiSetProperty` methods.